# Would a server fully protected by .htaccess hinder a $ git clone?

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess

I have an Apache server (MediaTemple (ve), if that matters) where each directory is password protected. A username and password is required to view any pages in said directory in the browser.

I am attempting to set up a Git repository in each of the directories. I have been successfully with installing Git, creating repos, and committing (via Terminal). The issues come when I attempt to clone the repo onto my local machine.

I type in the following (edited for obvious reasons):

```
$ git clone ssh://root@website.com/path/to/.git
```

I get asked this in return:

```
root@website.com's password:
```

I enter the password, it connects, and then I get thrown the following errors:

```
fatal: '/path/to/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I know that the path is a Git repository, as I was making commits to it earlier. My only thought is that the .htaccess is possibly causing the issue. I cannot take it down to test, as we have sensitive files hidden behind it.

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SSH, the `.htaccess` doesn’t come into play at all. What’s happening is that the SSH connection is failing. Probably a lack of a public/private key pair, or some other such. Try entering the `root` to SSH into the server instead of the `.htaccess` password.

I'd recommend *not* using `root` to do user-level tasks (like setting up git repos or other such), as permissions for `root` are always far stricter than any other user.

Instead create a user for you, and use that to SSH in. If you need to, use `sudo`, or `su root`, to do admin-level tasks, but try to avoid it if you can.